# Actual calculation of Coulomb energy in DFT softwares

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, ab-initio-calculations

I have a question about the actual calculation of classical Coulomb interaction term in density functional theory (DFT) softwares.

Of course I understand the form Coulomb energy as:

$\int\int \frac{\rho(r_i)\rho(r_j)}{|r_i - r_j|}dr_idr_j$,

but in the actual calculation, this term seems to be computationally expensive due to the distances between all grid points, $r_i$ and $r_j$, set in DFT softwares.

In reality, in a practical calculation, such as that of PySCF, even a small molecule has a large number (e.g. over 100,000) of grid points, so the calculation of all grid distances appears to be very expensive.

Does the actual calculations rely on specific technique for efficiently calculating the grid distances?

Comment: First note the equation you have written is for the Coulomb energy, not the potential (sort of). Secondly are you particularly interested in one kind of basis set? Plane-waves? Gaussians?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have fixed. I consider the calculation of organic molecules and Gaussian or PySCF.

Comment: For Gaussian basis sets, real codes use cutoffs for distances between the centers of basis sets

Comment: Poisson equation can be used or you mean the exact exchange.

Comment: Also are you interested only in molecular systems, or ones with periodic boundary conditions as well?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. First of all, I consider molecules, but with crystals, is the way to calculate Coulomb totally different?

Comment: For periodic systems, you can use the convolution theorem (observe that the Hartree potential, v(r_j) = ∫ dr_i n(r_i) / |r_i - r_j|, is just a convolution), i.e. Fourier transform the density and 1/R potential, take their product in reciprocal space and inverse Fourier transform to get the convolution. The FFTs would scale as N log N in the number of grid points.